# Grep output pattern

Tags: grep

If I have a bash file with following content:

```
ls \
/tmp
```

Is there a way to grep this file and get

```
ls \
/tmp
```

instead of

```
ls \
```

?

Please notice that other behaviors of grep should remain same if input is a large file and has other match patterns.

Thanks!

Comment: Your question is a little vague to me,can you post the current grep command your using?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming you want to treat the final `\` as a line continuation character, you can use `awk` to concatenate the lines:

```
awk '{ while( sub( "\\\\$", "" )) { getline n; $0 = $0 n; }} /ls/' input-file
```

This removes the line continuation character and combines everything into one line, then prints the line if if matches the regex `ls`.

Comment: This is great! Is it hard if I want add \ back?

Comment: Probably easiest to not delete it in the first place.  Use `awk '{ while( /\\$/ ) ... ` instead.

Answer (score 1):

You can use the *context* options, `-A` (lines after), `-B` (lines before), and `-C` (lines context, both before and after):

```
$ grep -A1 ls test.sh
ls \
/tmp
```

Comment: +1 for the answer. Shouldn't you use `-A1` instead of `-C1` so it matches what the OP wanted.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. What if the bash file contains:
ls \
/var \
/tmp